# show & hide div by checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-animate

please say me, what's wrong ?
we have many checkbox. OnClick any checkbox div "catdiv" must show with animate (bottom,0 %).

If checked checkbox is <1, "catdiv" must hide with animate...

```
<script>
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
$("#catdiv").animate ({bottom: "0%"), 500 );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ID` but maybe you need to use `class`?

```
<script>
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
$(".catdiv").animate ({bottom: "0%"), 500 );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(".catdiv").animate({bottom: "0%"}, 500 );
});
```

- You can use `$(this).is(':checked')` to check whether the check box
  is checked or not.
- For the `.catdiv`, it should have "`absolute`" as
  `position`. You can use its `ID` or `class` to select it.

Comment: thanks...how hide "catdiv" with animate on unchek checkbox?

Comment: You can do it this way: 
`$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(".catdiv").animate({bottom: "0%"}, 500 );
  }
});`